# What does PI in OSIsoft's 'PI System' stand for?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, complex-event-processing, osisoft

What does PI in [OSIsoft's 'PI System'](https://www.osisoft.com/why-pi-system) stand for?

I can't tell if it stands for the symbol/number Pi, or if it stands for a previous name for the technology, like 'Process Intelligence'.  PI is too close to the more common BI to be just a coincidence.

Note - There are Channel9 videos that demonstrate how MS uses OSIsoft to monitor some operations.  Links to the C9 videos are from the ['SQL 2008 R2'](https://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/R2-complex-event.aspx) CEP  pages.  The SQL CEP features are called StreamInsight.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

PI used to stand for "Plant Information". Now that the PI System suite of products does much more and is used in many different environments, PI is just "PI".

Answer (score 3):

PI stands for Plant Information or Process Information, depending on who you ask.

A little bit of history for you; before PI was used in various industries, it was mainly geared to oil/gas.  OSI used to stand for Oil Systems Incorporated.

Answer (score 2):

Mainly to store a large amount of historical data for industrial purposes.

A good example is when you need to develop an enhancement in your process to reduce the energy consuption then you can use the informations of each equipment and make plans to reduce it's energy consuption.

Other example is when you need to make industrial informations available for the entire corporation, as the state of a equipment (stopped or running). The PI System has it's own interfaces to make it possible.

Answer (score 0):

PI stands for process intelligence!whereby in its storage of information like intersection of matrices where there is small set of universe  which represent the system,that intersection has never been zero,like for pi it has information as long as  it is in connection with  the plant.